# Console.app needs color themes

Tags: macos, console, themes

Black text on white background hurts the eyes while perusing logs in [Console.app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_(OS_X)).

There used to be some hacks like [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030109064316126) to change the colors of the display in Console.app. But those hacks apparently no longer work in current versions such as Yosemite.

Any current ways to change Console colors in Mountain Lion or Yosemite?

Answer (score 1):

Try [decompiling](https://github.com/akahan/Nib-Decompiler) first, then editing this `NIB` file.

`/Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/LogWindow.nib`

Answer (score 0):

You can send feedback to Apple: apple.com/feedback

Comment: This should be a Comment rather than an Answer as it presents neither a solution nor a workaround.